# Approach for testing Multi tenant application using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

We need to do performance testing for a multi tenant application deployed on Azure cloud using jmeter, Please guide.

1. Need to do performance testing for 1-N Customers at a time,
   on-demand.
2. How to do performance testing for multilingual applications at a
   time for 1-N customers at a time on-demand.
3. If we use Azure Virtual machine and jmeter inside for load testing,
   does it scaleup in terms of memory and network on demand as per
   required load.

Please share any approaches or success stories on same.

Answer (score 0):

1. The number of concurrent users is configurable in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), [Open Model Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Open_Model_Thread_Group) or [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups), whatever you want to choose
2. JMeter acts on [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) level and knows nothing about the language, depending on your application implementation it can be either a part of the URL or application can guess the user's language from the [Accept-Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) header which can be set using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager)
3. You can enable [auto-scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-overview) but it will work only for CPU. For the memory [JMeter relies on Java's `-Xmx` option](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/jmeter.bat#L151) which defines the maximum amount of RAM it can consume. So I would rather go for [Azure Load Testing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/load-testing/) or [JMeter Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) and allocate the necessary amount of virtual machines for conducting the necessary load.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your inputs ,Can you share link for whitepaper /success story on performance testing on multi-Tenant application.